# Having problems with retrieving, saving, and sending text from multiple edittext boxes

Tags: android-intent, android-edittext

I have been trying many different ways from different tutorials, question responses, etc. and still cannot get my app to not only retrieve the text from multiple edittext, but then save into an object, and then move to new activity passing the text to be displayed as a confirmation. I will post both attempts I have written.

1st attempt
    package com.zombiecatandroidapp;

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RatingBar;

public class ChefCookRateActivity extends Activity implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public final static String FIRST_NAME_MESSAGE = "com.zombiecatandroidapp.MESSAGE";
    public final static String LAST_NAME_MESSAGE = "com.zombiecatandroidapp.MESSAGE";
    public final static String COMPANY_NAME_CHEF_COOK_MESSAGE = "com.zombiecatandroidapp.MESSAGE";
    public final static String COMPANY_ADDRESS_CHEF_COOK_MESSAGE = "com.zombiecatandroidapp.MESSAGE";
    public final static String COMPANY_CITY_CHEF_COOK_MESSAGE = "com.zombiecatandroidapp.MESSAGE";
    public final static String COMPANY_STATE_CHEF_COOK_MESSAGE = "com.zombiecatandroidapp.MESSAGE";
    public final static String COMPANY_ZIP_CHEF_COOK_MESSAGE = "com.zombiecatandroidapp.MESSAGE";
    public final static String FOOD_RATE_CHEf_COOK_BAR_MESSAGE = "com.zombiecatandroidapp.MESSAGE";
    public final static String FILE_NAME = "C:\\Users\\Cassey\\AppData\\Local\\Development\\ProjectFile\\ChefCookRating.ser";
    ChefCook person = new ChefCook();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chef_cook_rate);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.chef_cook_rate, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void startSubmitDisplay(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayInfoActivity.class);

        final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.first_name);
        String firstName = editText.getText().toString();

        final EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.last_name);
        String lastName = editText1.getText().toString();

        final EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.company_name_chef_cook);
        String companyNameChefCook = editText2.getText().toString();

        final EditText editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.company_address_chef_cook);
        String companyAddressChefCook = editText3.getText().toString();

        final EditText editText4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.company_city_chef_cook);
        String companyCityChefCook = editText4.getText().toString();

        final EditText editText5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.company_state_chef_cook);
        String companyStateChefCook = editText5.getText().toString();

        final EditText editText6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.company_zip_chef_cook);
        String companyZipChefCook = editText6.getText().toString();
        int companyZipChefCookConvert = Integer.parseInt(companyZipChefCook);

        RatingBar ratingbar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.food_rate_chef_cook_bar);
        String foodRateChefCookBar = String.valueOf(ratingbar.getRating());
        int foodRateChefCookBarConvert = Integer.parseInt(foodRateChefCookBar);

        person.setFirstName(firstName);
        person.setLastName(lastName);
        person.setCompanyName(companyNameChefCook);
        person.setCompanyAddress(companyAddressChefCook);
        person.setCompanyCity(companyCityChefCook);
        person.setCompanyState(companyStateChefCook);
        person.setCompanyZip(companyZipChefCookConvert);
        person.setRating(firstName, lastName, foodRateChefCookBarConvert, 1);

        saveChefCook(person);

        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void saveChefCook(ChefCook person) {
        try{
             // Serialize data object to a file
             ObjectOutputStream fileOut = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("FILE_NAME"));
             fileOut.writeObject(person);
             fileOut.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

With the next activity looking like this.
    package com.zombiecatandroidapp;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Intent;

public class DisplayInfoActivity extends Activity {

    TextView textView3 = null;
    TextView textView4 = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_info);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(ChefCookRateActivity.FIRST_NAME_MESSAGE);
        message += intent.getStringExtra(ChefCookRateActivity.LAST_NAME_MESSAGE);
        String message2 = intent.getStringExtra(ChefCookRateActivity.COMPANY_NAME_CHEF_COOK_MESSAGE);
        String message3 = intent.getStringExtra(ChefCookRateActivity.COMPANY_ADDRESS_CHEF_COOK_MESSAGE);
        String message4 = intent.getStringExtra(ChefCookRateActivity.COMPANY_CITY_CHEF_COOK_MESSAGE);
        message4 += intent.getStringExtra(ChefCookRateActivity.COMPANY_STATE_CHEF_COOK_MESSAGE);
        message4 += intent.getStringExtra(ChefCookRateActivity.COMPANY_ZIP_CHEF_COOK_MESSAGE);
        String message5 = intent.getStringExtra(ChefCookRateActivity.FOOD_RATE_CHEf_COOK_BAR_MESSAGE);

        // Create the text view
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText(message);

        TextView textView2 = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText(message2);

        TextView textView3 = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText(message3);

        TextView textView4 = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText(message4);


        TextView textView5 = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText(message5);


        // Set the text view as the activity layout
        setContentView(textView);
        if(textView2 != null) {
            setContentView(textView2);
        }        
        if(textView3 != null) {
            setContentView(textView3);
        }
        if(textView4 != null) {
            setContentView(textView4);
        }
        setContentView(textView5);

}


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_info, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

And then the 2nd attempt is this.
    package com.zombiecatandroidapp;

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RatingBar;

public class ChefCookRateActivity extends Activity implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public final static String FILE_NAME = "C:\\Users\\Cassey\\AppData\\Local\\Development\\ProjectFile\\ChefCookRating.ser";
    // get Edit Text component
    final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.first_name);
    final EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.last_name);
    final EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.company_name_chef_cook);
    final EditText editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.company_address_chef_cook);
    final EditText editText4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.company_city_chef_cook);
    final EditText editText5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.company_state_chef_cook);
    final EditText editText6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.company_zip_chef_cook);
    final RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.food_rate_chef_cook_bar);
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public String companyNameChefCook;
    public String companyAddressChefCook;
    public String companyCityChefCook;
    public String companyStateChefCook;
    public int companyZipChefCookConvert;
    private String foodRateChefCookBar;
    int foodRateChefCookBarConvert = Integer.parseInt(foodRateChefCookBar);
    ChefCook person = new ChefCook();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chef_cook_rate);

        addKeyListener();

        person.setFirstName(firstName);
        person.setLastName(lastName);
        person.setCompanyName(companyNameChefCook);
        person.setCompanyAddress(companyAddressChefCook);
        person.setCompanyCity(companyCityChefCook);
        person.setCompanyState(companyStateChefCook);
        person.setCompanyZip(companyZipChefCookConvert);
        person.setRating(firstName, lastName, foodRateChefCookBarConvert, 1);

        saveChefCook(person);
}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.chef_cook_rate, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void addKeyListener() {

        // add a keylistener to keep track of user input
        editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            // if keydown and enter is pressed
            if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    editText.getText().toString();
                    firstName = editText.getText().toString();
                    return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        });

        editText1.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            // if keydown and enter is pressed
            if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    editText1.getText().toString();
                    lastName = editText.getText().toString();
                    return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        });

        editText2.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            // if keydown and enter is pressed
            if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    editText2.getText().toString();
                    companyNameChefCook = editText.getText().toString();
                    return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        });

        editText3.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            // if keydown and enter is pressed
            if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    editText3.getText().toString();
                    companyAddressChefCook = editText.getText().toString();
                    return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        });

        editText4.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            // if keydown and enter is pressed
            if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    editText4.getText().toString();
                    companyCityChefCook = editText.getText().toString();
                    return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        });

        editText5.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                // if keydown and enter is pressed
                if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        editText5.getText().toString();
                        companyStateChefCook = editText.getText().toString();
                        return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            });

        editText6.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                // if keydown and enter is pressed
                if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        editText6.getText().toString();
                        String companyZipChefCook = editText6.getText().toString();
                        companyZipChefCookConvert = Integer.parseInt(companyZipChefCook);
                        return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            });

        ratingBar.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                // if keydown and enter is pressed
                if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        foodRateChefCookBar = String.valueOf(ratingBar.getRating());
                        return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            });
    } 

    public void startSubmitDisplay(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayInfoActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void saveChefCook(ChefCook person) {
        try{
             // Serialize data object to a file
             ObjectOutputStream fileOut = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("FILE_NAME"));
             fileOut.writeObject(person);
             fileOut.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

The display activity for this one I haven't written yet because when I try to at least long this activity my emulator crashes with Activity thread errors. Something about source not found.

```
3rd attempt looks like this
package com.zombiecatandroidapp;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RatingBar;

public class ChefCookRateActivity extends Activity implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public final static String FILE_NAME = "C:\\Users\\Cassey\\AppData\\Local\\Development\\ProjectFile\\ChefCookRating.ser";
    // get Edit Text component
    final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.first_name);
    final EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.last_name);
    final EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.company_name_chef_cook);
    final EditText editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.company_address_chef_cook);
    final EditText editText4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.company_city_chef_cook);
    final EditText editText5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.company_state_chef_cook);
    final EditText editText6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.company_zip_chef_cook);
    final RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.food_rate_chef_cook_bar);
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public String companyNameChefCook;
    public String companyAddressChefCook;
    public String companyCityChefCook;
    public String companyStateChefCook;
    public int companyZipChefCookConvert;
    private String foodRateChefCookBar;
    int foodRateChefCookBarConvert = Integer.parseInt(foodRateChefCookBar);
    ChefCook person = new ChefCook();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chef_cook_rate);

}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.chef_cook_rate, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void addKeyListener() {

        // add a keylistener to keep track of user input
        editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            // if keydown and enter is pressed
            if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    editText.getText().toString();
                    firstName = editText.getText().toString();
                    return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        });

        editText1.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            // if keydown and enter is pressed
            if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    editText1.getText().toString();
                    lastName = editText.getText().toString();
                    return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        });

        editText2.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            // if keydown and enter is pressed
            if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    editText2.getText().toString();
                    companyNameChefCook = editText.getText().toString();
                    return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        });

        editText3.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            // if keydown and enter is pressed
            if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    editText3.getText().toString();
                    companyAddressChefCook = editText.getText().toString();
                    return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        });

        editText4.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            // if keydown and enter is pressed
            if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    editText4.getText().toString();
                    companyCityChefCook = editText.getText().toString();
                    return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        });

        editText5.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                // if keydown and enter is pressed
                if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        editText5.getText().toString();
                        companyStateChefCook = editText.getText().toString();
                        return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            });

        editText6.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                // if keydown and enter is pressed
                if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        editText6.getText().toString();
                        String companyZipChefCook = editText6.getText().toString();
                        companyZipChefCookConvert = Integer.parseInt(companyZipChefCook);
                        return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            });

        ratingBar.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                // if keydown and enter is pressed
                if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        foodRateChefCookBar = String.valueOf(ratingBar.getRating());
                        return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            });
    } 

    public void startSubmitDisplay(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayInfoActivity.class);
                        addKeyListener();

        person.setFirstName(firstName);
        person.setLastName(lastName);
        person.setCompanyName(companyNameChefCook);
        person.setCompanyAddress(companyAddressChefCook);
        person.setCompanyCity(companyCityChefCook);
        person.setCompanyState(companyStateChefCook);
        person.setCompanyZip(companyZipChefCookConvert);
        person.setRating(firstName, lastName, foodRateChefCookBarConvert, 1);

        saveChefCook(person);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void saveChefCook(ChefCook person) {
        try{
             // Serialize data object to a file
             ObjectOutputStream fileOut = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("FILE_NAME"));
             fileOut.writeObject(person);
             fileOut.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Again, the display activity for this one I haven't written yet because when I try to at least long this activity my emulator crashes with Activity thread errors. Something about source not found.

I tried a 4th version which looks like this.

```
package com.zombiecatandroidapp;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RatingBar;

public class ChefCookRateActivity extends Activity implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public final static String FILE_NAME = "C:\\Users\\Cassey\\AppData\\Local\\Development\\ProjectFile\\ChefCookRating.ser";
    // get Edit Text component
    final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.first_name);
    final EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.last_name);
    final EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.company_name_chef_cook);
    final EditText editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.company_address_chef_cook);
    final EditText editText4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.company_city_chef_cook);
    final EditText editText5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.company_state_chef_cook);
    final EditText editText6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.company_zip_chef_cook);
    final RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.food_rate_chef_cook_bar);
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public String companyNameChefCook;
    public String companyAddressChefCook;
    public String companyCityChefCook;
    public String companyStateChefCook;
    public int companyZipChefCookConvert;
    private String foodRateChefCookBar;
    int foodRateChefCookBarConvert = Integer.parseInt(foodRateChefCookBar);
    ChefCook person = new ChefCook();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chef_cook_rate);

        addOnFocusChangeListener();

}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.chef_cook_rate, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void startSubmitDisplay(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayInfoActivity.class);

        person.setFirstName(firstName);
        person.setLastName(lastName);
        person.setCompanyName(companyNameChefCook);
        person.setCompanyAddress(companyAddressChefCook);
        person.setCompanyCity(companyCityChefCook);
        person.setCompanyState(companyStateChefCook);
        person.setCompanyZip(companyZipChefCookConvert);
        person.setRating(firstName, lastName, foodRateChefCookBarConvert, 1);

        saveChefCook(person);

        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void saveChefCook(ChefCook person) {
        try{
             // Serialize data object to a file
             ObjectOutputStream fileOut = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("FILE_NAME"));
             fileOut.writeObject(person);
             fileOut.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

public void addOnFocusChangeListener() {

    // add a focuslistener to keep track of user input
    editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus) {
            editText.getText().toString();
            firstName = editText.getText().toString();

            }
        }
    });

    editText1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus) {
            editText1.getText().toString();
            lastName = editText.getText().toString();

            }
        }
    });

    editText2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus) {
            editText2.getText().toString();
            companyNameChefCook = editText.getText().toString();

            }
        }
    });

    editText3.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus) {
            editText3.getText().toString();
            companyAddressChefCook = editText.getText().toString();

            }
        }
    });

    editText4.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus) {
            editText4.getText().toString();
            companyCityChefCook = editText.getText().toString();

            }
        }
    });

    editText5.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus) {
            editText5.getText().toString();
            companyStateChefCook = editText.getText().toString();

            }
        }
    });

    editText6.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus) {
            editText6.getText().toString();
            String companyZipChefCook = editText.getText().toString();
            companyZipChefCookConvert = Integer.parseInt(companyZipChefCook);

            }
        }
    });

    ratingBar.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            // if keydown and enter is pressed
            if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    foodRateChefCookBar = String.valueOf(ratingBar.getRating());
                    return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Again it simply stops my emulator.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what the exact problem is, but whatever you do, *don't try to serialize an entire Activity*.

I would instead make Person serializable, and provide it in the intent to the second activity. E.g.:

```
intent.putSerializable(EXTRA_PERSON, person);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I am trying to retrieve the text from the edittext fields from there I am trying to assign the information to the appropriate chefcook object variables and then save the chefcook object and so far that's it, but I would like to then pass the information to my next page to display the information that is saved. I tried doing as you suggested with the serialization, but it errors saying I have to add a cast to bundle and then errors saying you can't cast an intent to bundle. And I realized I said it stops my emulator, but it doesn't, it stops my app.

Comment: There are numerous problems with your code snippets, so it's hard to say exactly what is causing your troubles. Just to name a few problems: you're trying to read strings from the intent that you never put into it; you're assigning different messages to the same TextView; your setting the content view to different text views, one after another.

Comment: As for why your app is crashing: debug it. At the least take a look at the stack trace.

Comment: I see what you mean about the text view. Can't believe I missed that. I have ran the debugger on it and when I do, the first error that shows up is in the Activity class itself, line 1189, and I don't understand why. This is my first Android app so I'm still learning everything about it. It's my final project for my final class before graduating.

Comment: Can you follow the stack trace up to where it enters the SDK from your code?